# Q.all is not working

Tags: javascript, node.js, protractor, q

I have a problem with my node.js e2e test. I want to wait for 2 promises to resolve. But for some reason when I use Q.all it is just freezing my app. I am using kriskowal's Q 1.0.0.

This works:

```
var doStuff = function() {
    var promiseA = getPromiseA();
    return promiseA;
}


var prepareTestData = function(done) {
    doSomething()
    .then(doStuff)
    .then(done);
}
```

But this does not:

```
var doStuff = function() {
    var promiseA = getPromiseA();
    var promiseB = getPromiseB();
    return [promiseA, promiseB];
}


var prepareTestData = function(done) {
    doSomething()
    .all(doStuff)
    .then(done);
}
```

Can someone help me out what I am missing?

Comment: You're not calling Q.all anywhere - you should `return Q.all([promiseA, promiseB])`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*** Updated ***

The simplified answer to your question is that the all() prototype method doesn't take parameters, so .all(doStuff) is only calling .all() on the promise returned by doSomething() and doStuff ends up being an argument that's never used.  The simplest solution is to use nikc.org's solution.

Comment: Note, however, that this executes `doStuff` _synchronously_, not after `doSomething` has finished. (Unless, of course, `doSomething` is also synchronous, but since it's returning a promise, one can assume it isn't.) /cc @Moezales

Comment: Surprisingly, you are correct.  This isn't at all the behavior I expected and the documentation doesn't seem to indicate when all() is invoked.  I assumed all was analogous to then, but only for a collection of promises rather than a single promise.  Do you know where this behavior is documentation, as I'm not finding this described in the [documentation](https://github.com/kriskowal/q/wiki/API-Reference).

Comment: This has nothing to do with Q, but your code. You're not passing a function to Q.all, but the return value of a function call. (Note the () after doStuff)

Comment: In fact, doStuff will always run before doSomething in this format. Don't know what I was thinking.

Comment: I'm aware my example passes in the return value of the function rather than the function itself, but I fail to see how this relates to my comment concerning my expectations that all() would behave like then()  (i.e that it would only execute after the resolution of the promise it's called on). As far as the sequence of events, I found in my first example that doSomething() did complete first, but only by virtue of it doing synchronous work before returning.  Technically, doSomething() will always execute first as the call to all belongs to doSomething's return value.

Comment: The difference that might be confusing, is between the static `Q.all` and the `promise.all` methods. Both similarly expect an array, but `promise.all` expects it as an argument at invoke time, not at "sequence declaration time" (for the lack of a better expression), for a sequence of operations is essentially what your describe when chaining promises. Personally, I'm surprised `.all` doesn't accept a function, but is always only an array reduction on the previous operation's return value only, returning a thenable.

Comment: After looking at the source, I finally see what you are saying.  I'll update the answer to reflect the correction in my understanding.

Comment: Thanks for bearing with me.

Comment: Ditto. (I've stumbled over this myself earlier.)

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways to use `.all()` in Q.

One is to use `Q.all()` on an array of promises to create a promise whose result is an array of all the resolutions of those promises.

```
var doStuff = function() {
    var promiseA = getPromiseA();
    var promiseB = getPromiseB();
    return Q.all([promiseA, promiseB]);
}


var prepareTestData = function(done) {
    doSomething()
    .then(doStuff)     // use then here
    .then(done);
}
```

The other (as shown in nikc.org's answer) is to call `.all()` on a promise whose result is an array of promises. This will produce a new promise whose result is an array of the resolutions of all those promises:

```
var doStuff = function() {
    var promiseA = getPromiseA();
    var promiseB = getPromiseB();
    return [promiseA, promiseB];
}


var prepareTestData = function(done) {
    doSomething()
    .then(doStuff)
    .all()
    .then(done);
}
```

In both cases, the result passsed to `done` will be an array with the resolved values of `promiseA` and `promiseB`.

Answer (score 0):

The call to `Promise.all` should be after calling `doStuff` which is returning the array of promises. Alternatively, you `return Q.all(Array)` from `doStuff`.

```
var prepareTestData = function(done) {
    doSomething()
    .then(doStuff) // array returned here
    .all()         // all creates a promise of promises
    .then(done);
}
```